# Crossfire different graphic cards

Tags: graphics-card, crossfire

Is it possible to crossfire different cards? Like a Radeon 6950 and a Radeon 7970?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This image may help (which is not on the duplicate page). You may have to right click on the image and select 'View Image' (or similar depending on your browser) as it's small due to the dimensions of each post! This has the models you are after.

[image]
[Large image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOeZU.jpg)